# css is working different in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a header with box-shadow style on two div tags. and a header div tag .
I wrote that in notepad++ and it works perfect. but when i want to use it in my asp.net page it does not show shadows and also its padding and the height of elements shown different. 
I try to open in Firefox and IE and the html file is working perfect but the asp file has different .CSS but i use same .CSS file for both...
any body know why this is happening ?

here the code :

```
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title> طراحی وبسایت</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowMenuMobile(){
     if( document.getElementById("Menu").style.display=="none")
         document.getElementById("Menu").style.display="block";
    else
         document.getElementById("Menu").style.display="none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body >

<div class="gridContainer">
  <div id="Header">
    <table  id="headerTable"  >
      <tr>
        <td id="SocialLink" >
        <a href="#"><img src="img/instaHover.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Telegram.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td id="Contact"><a id="EmailLink" href="#">info@mangochip.com</a></td>
        <td id="temp" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="SignUp" ><a href="#">ثبت نام</a></td>
        <td id="Login" ><a href="#">ورود</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div id="btnMenu" >
    <button id="btnDrop" onclick="ShowMenuMobile()" >
        <div class="btnMobile"></div>
        <div class="btnMobile"></div>
        <div class="btnMobile"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="Menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">صفحه نخست</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">طراحی وبسایت</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">نمونه کارها</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">طراحی نرم افزار</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">پروژه های آزاد</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">مقالات</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">راهنمای سفارش</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">درباره ما</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Logo"><img src="img/logo1.png"/></div>
</div>
```

and css file is :

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    direction:rtl;

}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.gridContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #1f2348;

}

#Header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    direction:rtl;
    background-color:#1f2348;
    /*padding:11px;*/
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#Menu {
    font-family:menu;
    font-size:24px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 83.0508%;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:35px;

}
ul{ 

    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li{
    float:right;

}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #1f2348;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:3px solid transparent;
}

li a:hover {
   /* background-color: #b0d24c;*/
   display:block;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:3px solid #fcb037;
    color:#1f2348;
    margin-top:5px; 
}

#Logo {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.6949%;
    width: 15.2542%;
    display: block;
}
#headerTable{
    font-family:header;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:100%;
    color:#fcb037;
    padding:12px;

    }
#Login {

    text-align:right;
    padding-right:2ex;
}
#Login a{
    color:#fcb037;
}
#Login a:hover{
    color:#facb29;
}
#SignUp{
    border-left:1px solid;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:2ex;

}
#SignUp a{
    color:#fcb037;
}
#SignUp a:hover{
    color:#facb29;
}
#Contact {
    font-family:email;
    text-align:right;
    padding-left:0.5ex;
    padding-right:2ex;
    font-family:email;
    font-size:18px;

}
#Contact a{
    color:#fcb037;
}
#Contact a:hover{
    color:#facb29;
}
#SocialLink {
    border-left:1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:0.5ex;

}
#SocialLink a{
    color:#fcb037;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your question is quite confusing. You said that page renders properly on IE and Firefox but not in you "asp.net page". Do you mean the HTML Designer within Visual Studio?

Comment: @pjc89 i design the css and the html in an html page using notepad++ but now when i importing them to visual studio website the css is changed and i dont know why ... that is my question i open same page in visual studio but when it runs it its style is changing how should i fix this ? should i change all the style again ?

Comment: Are you sure the path to your css sheets are correct? Do you have both sheets  on different places (boilerplate.css, css/layout.css)?. maybe you could try: <link id="linkid" runat="server" href="~/YOURCSSFOLDER/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: yes i am sure they are correct paths but it looks diifferent when wants to load from IIS server

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a 'hard refresh' of the page in the browser. not F5, but `Ctrl+F5` so you have the newest css. I tried in firefox and it seems ok here too. (yes, your question is kind of confusing.)

Comment: even with hard refresh it shows different style .. and i cannot understand why ... my question i think is clear ... i design an html page with style out side vs and now i imported it to my project... it shows different style when i imported it to vs project ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clean/rebuild the solution?